# mysql_real_escape_string working perfectly in localhost, not working online

Tags: php, filter, localhost

On the page http://www.immocorbati.be/tehuur.php the filter functions don't work as they should. Only "Prijsklasse" (price) works. However, if you filter on "Gemeente" (area) Boom for example, it should return 1 home, but it says none are found. Same with "Type" studio should return 3 but doesn't return anything and "Slaapkamer" (bedrooms) 3 slaapkamers should return 1 home, but again none are shown.

**What I don't understand is why it works perfectly on localhost**, and it works half and half online, because that means the function IS reached. Here are the files. Maybe someone has some pointers as why this happens? Is it possibe that it is database related? But all the other functions in the backend etc. work as they should.

```
class Pand
{

    //DB settings - Don't worry these are correct
    private $m_sHost = "??????";
    private $m_sUser = "????????";
    private $m_sPassword = "??????";
    private $m_sDatabase = "????????";     

    public function GetToonPandenHuurFilter()
    {
    //de panden worden op pagina getoond volgens filter
            if ($link = mysqli_connect($this->m_sHost, $this->m_sUser, $this->m_sPassword, $this->m_sDatabase))
            {

                    $b = $_POST['typewoning'];
                    $p = $_POST['plaats'];
                    $s = $_POST['slaapkamers'];
                    $k = $_POST['prijsklasse'];


                    $sSql = "select * from tblpand WHERE PandVerkoopstype='Te huur' AND PandOnline='Ja'";
                    if ($b !== 'all') {
                            $sSql .= " AND PandBebouwing='" . mysql_real_escape_string($b) . "'";
                    }                      
                    if ($p !== 'all') {
                            $sSql .= " AND PandPostcodeGemeente='" . mysql_real_escape_string($p) . "'";
                    }
                    if ($s !== 'all') {
                            $sSql .= "AND PandSlaapkamers='" . mysql_real_escape_string($s) . "'";
                    }
                    if ($k == '0') {
                            $sSql .= "";
                    }
                    if ($k == '1') {
                            $sSql .= "AND PandPrijs <'" . 301 . "'";
                    }
                    if ($k == '2') {
                            $sSql .= "AND PandPrijs <'" . 501 . "'";
                    }
                    if ($k == '3') {
                            $sSql .= "AND PandPrijs <'" . 701 . "'";
                    }
                    if ($k == '4') {
                            $sSql .= "AND PandPrijs <'" . 701 . "'";
                    }


                    $rResult = mysqli_query($link, $sSql);
                    return $rResult;
            }
            else
            {
                    // er kon geen connectie gelegd worden met de databank
                    throw new Exception('Ooh my, something terrible happened to the database connection'); 
            }      
            mysqli_close($link);
    }
}
```

I added error reporting and the feedback says:

```
mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user ''@'10.246.64.177'
(using password: NO) in /customers/e/a/b/immocorbati.be/httpd.www/classes/Pand.class.php on line 1086
```

Line 1086 is:

```
$sSql .= " AND PandBebouwing='" . mysql_real_escape_string($b) . "'";
```

Comment: Please do some more debugging. Insert debugging statements, `var_dump` variables, narrow down where exactly it starts to fail. We aren't in any better position to do that than you are.

Comment: When testing code, you need to ensure you have display_errors enabled. If there's something failing you on the server, PHP will likely be able to detail it.  At the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`   then disable that later when you deploy to a live environment.

Comment: Okay, I'll start with this.

Comment: `Is it possibe that it is database related` - your querying a database right? Then sure it's possible.  What is this `$b` `$p`, you can use more then one letter, it makes it a bit easier to read if you name it the same as the key you are using, ie. `$b = $_POST['typewoning']` reads better as `$typewoning = $_POST['typewoning']`  and these ` if ($k == '0') {` should be `}else if ($k == '1') {`

Comment: Thank you for the help so far. As you guess, I was in a state of panick. I added error reporting and the feedback says:
`mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user ''@'10.246.64.177' (using password: NO) in /customers/e/a/b/immocorbati.be/httpd.www/classes/Pand.class.php on line 1086 –` 

Line 1086 is:
`$sSql .= " AND PandBebouwing='" . mysql_real_escape_string($b) . "'";`

As far as I know,  data for connection works, since it works in other functions too and is linked to in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string` requires a database connection to do its work. `mysql_real_escape_string` belongs to the mysql API. You're establishing a connection using mysqli. mysql and mysqli are two entirely different database APIs; a mysqli connection is useless for mysql_*. mysql has the bad habit of implicitly (trying to) establishing a connection when needed. On your localhost, the implicit connection it's trying to establish happens to work (default username, no password etc.). On your host, it doesn't.

**Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string` when using mysqli. Use [mysqli's parameter binding API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or at the very least [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string).**

Comment: This is the answer. I'm happy I was finding this out too. Stupid, but it's also extremely illogical that the combination of mysql and mysqli works in localhost. I'm implementing the binding API now. Thank you.

Comment: True, which is one of the reasons mysql is deprecated and should not be touched, not even with a ten foot pole.